Setting the maximum width of a form on a website
I am currently designing a form on a website and I am wondering if there is an ideal width for designing the form. I am putting two fields in one line now, but I feel like the form is still too wide on a 24-inch or 27-inch monitor. I know that 66 characters is the ideal line width for websites with text. But what about forms? Does this principle also work for forms?

Forms work on a different principle which is based on shortest path of cursor movement. The 66-character rule will probably apply to an individual input field but not the entire form, because when a user is using an input, only the label and the input box are the points of focus for that moment.

In order to solve your problem I think that it is important to follow some tenets, one of them is to use your defined grid for the whole site. Once you set that is important to arrange your elements to make your form easy to read for your users. In the example below you can see that I'm not using the whole grid to place the form elements. It is based more on your experience and instinct, how you will define the final design.

That number you mentioned could vary from 50 to 75 characters per line. Actually I'll put a good paper that documented the best approach to reach a good readability and how it was defined from 50 to 75 c/l. Also, that number is set for large amount of text or paragraphs.
Readability: The Optimal Line Length

Use typography rules to calculate content width for your given typeface and font size.
This is useful not just for forms but your content layouts in general.
Use calculators where you enter your type and size and it will give you the optimal content width:

https://grtcalculator.com/
https://typescale.com/


Type is one of pillars of design. Learn about the typography and it will help you a lot in your work:

Books: "The Elements of Typographic Style", "Thinking with Type"
Watch Helvetica, a fantastic film by Gary Hustvit
There's a great free course, Betterwebtype by Matej Latin

